# Read from firebase database with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm struggling to get the value I need from Firebase

I have this setup

```
MyAppName:
- version : 1.0
```

and I am trying to get it like so:

```
let refHandle = dbRootRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
        print(postDict)
    })
```

Can someone help me get the **1.0** from the database?

p.s - no errors and nothing in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
let ref = "path to your Firebase/version" //point directly to the version node

ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot?.value) //prints 1
})
```

Testing rules: set to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: again, nothing in the console

Comment: @JamesG I just ran the exact same code using the same Firebase structure as in your question. That tells me you may have a rules issue. Try temporarily setting your rules to read and write to true. I also changed my code in the answer to better match your structure.

Comment: Did the job. But I had to change the second String to Double and also the as String to as Double. but thank you.

Comment: @JamesG You may want to consider storing everything as strings as Firebase. It's a lot more flexible, causes less conversions and will keep your data consistent. You can always *let myDouble = Double(myString)* once the string is read in. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks will keep that in mind. Have you used firebase a lot? Im rather new and the rules thing confused me. How do I make that version in firebase accessable to read to everyone but make sure that the rest of it need auth?

Comment: @JamesG Yes.. I have used Firebase a lot. Unfortunately I am now just a lurker since they no longer support macOS. Rules are super challenging for beginners to wrap their brain around. I would suggest reading through the [Understanding Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). Beyond that it's a lot of learn-by-doing. Work with it and when you get stuck, post a separate question and we'll try to help. Oh, the [Firebase Legacy Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html) documentation is way better at explaining Rules. Review that as well.

Comment: legend. Thanks squire.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have pod file configured? and also App Delegate configuration? Google Plist File Added? Getting a Value from Firebase is pretty straightforward,. Follow this tutorial and you would be ready to go! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joVi3thZOqc&index=10&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLn-elkHPhDuuwdCZ93BXnrB

Thats the only way I can help with the information you gave about your problem, hope it helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Everything i set up. I can create users etc... I just need the code to get that value I posted.

Comment: Example: 
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let priceRef = rootRef.child("price")
        priceRef.observe(.value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            self.priceLabel.text = (snap.value as AnyObject).description
        }
    }

}